# When prompted to add a certificate or profile to connect to a secured WiFi network, how can I tell if it's safe to install it?

Tags: certificates, wifi

Sometimes when I connect to secured WiFi networks on my computer, such as my internet provider's WiFi hotspots around the city, I'm asked to add a certificate to my certificate store. When I'm on my iPhone, the way this manifests is that I'm asked to install a profile.

I vaguely remember profiles and certificates being used maliciously, but I don't remember the specifics.

Is it still possible for these certificates to be used maliciously? Can they be used for SSL MITM? How can you tell if it's safe to install these certificates or profiles?

Comment: you should be able to tell who published/vouched for the cert, or else it's not worth much.

Comment: If the certificate is a root certificate then it can use it to sign for any website. Now, that doesn't mean that is what they are using it for, it could for example be marked as an authentication certificate for setting up an SSL VPN tunnel, this would actually be more secure across an open wifi hotspot if shared by secure means. Ultimately without more information about the certificate and the install parameters used, we can not know how it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Never install a certificate you don't trust.
If you trust a certificate, the company/ person that issued the cert can mitm (and certainly will) any https connection you make. The system is often used by companies to monitor their employees activities. Would you accept that for your personal data ? I think not...

Comment: well, I've issued certificates that I haven't performed a mitm with.... Just because I could, does not mean I will. It is truly about trust though.

Comment: Oh to add to that, openvpn can use preshared certificates for client/server authentication, this would then allow all traffic to be down an encrypted tunnel between the device and the vpn server across the open wifi hotspot.

Comment: I think that your answer is mostly accurate. What keeps me from up-voting is the claim that “The system is often used by companies to monitor their employees activities.” Do you have references that back this up? I know that it would technically be possible but very unethical and almost certainly illegal.